# In a large document with many comments how do you review everything, both open and resolved comments, page by page?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-drive-comments

The 'Comments' button allows me to see the comments in date order but that doesn't give me the context of the page it was on. I have no idea when some of the comments where made, that I am looking for, because they were not my comments. There are so many comments it makes it difficult to find specific ones.

When I do find a comment I need to revisit, I have to reopen it to see it on  the page.  There are so many comments on the documents I do not want to reopen them all.

So is there a setting to allow me to see both open and resolved comments on the page they were originally entered?

Comment: Welcome. The disposition of comments has been a long, drawn out saga for users. Google has also removed the `getComments()` & `setComments` methods from AppsScript and declared that they are no prioritising any substitute tools. You would have noticed that in the course of your research. To the best of my limited knowledge, the answer to your question is, regrettably, "no".

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to be the answer I found too but was hoping I had just missed 'something'. Such a shame Google wants to make life harder for business users.